# Schutz and spacetime diagrams

Tags: spacetime, reference-frames, relativity

I've been struggling with understanding basic spacetime diagrams in the first chapter of Schutz's book on General Relativity. I don't get why the slope of the t prime axis of a moving observer is 1/beta. I can understand how using the Lorenz derivations will give you such a result but Schutz presents ST diagrams before he moves on to the algebraic form of SR. So is there an argument from the constancy of the velocity of light alone that i am missing?
Once I take the slope of the t prime line as a given it's not a problem to understand the slope of the x prime line.
My background: studied engineering many years ago, now trying to understand GR out of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an inertial observer whose spacetime coordinates I will label with $(x, ct)$. A second observer moves with constant velocity $v$ wrt to the first one, their frame of reference will have coordinates $(x', ct')$, the position of the second observer is simply $x = v t = \beta (ct)$, with $\beta = v/c$.

The important thing to realize is that the coordinates of the second observer in their frame is simply $ct' = 0$. So the line that corresponds to $ct = x/\beta$ must be equal to the line $ct' = 0$. From this you can conclude that the tangent of the angle between the axis $ct$ and $ct'$ must be $\beta$

Comment: Got it. Every point on the vt/c line in the coordinate system of the static observer corresponds to some time value t'>0 and x'=0 in the coordinate system of the moving observer since in his own coordinate system he is not moving, and therefore it is nothing but the t' axis of the coordinates of the moving observer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah - thanks, folks. Once I got caverac's point that the t' line corresponds to x'=0 in the coordinate system of the moving observer, it was quite clear. The calibration of the axes is discussed next in Schutz's book, which I can follow reasonably well. Do need to figure out how to get Greek symbols in my posts...

Comment: @Ronsaik Follow [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it is a great reference

Answer (score 0):

> I don't get why the slope of the t prime axis of a moving observer is
>   1/beta.

(1) The $ct'$ axis is the world line of the origin of the (inertial) primed coordinate system.

(2) The origin of the primed coordinate system has (constant) speed $v$ in the unprimed coordinate system.

(3) The position of the primed origin (assuming standard configuration) in the unprimed coordinate system is thus $vt$.

It follows that the slope of the world line of the primed origin in the unprimed coordinates is $$\frac{ct}{vt} = \frac{c}{v} = \frac{1}{\beta}$$

Thus, the slope of the $ct'$ axis is $\frac{1}{\beta}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that Galilean physics is all you need to answer this question. If you draw the position-vs-time graph of a plane moving with velocity v, you have a line with slope v. If you reorient the axes so that time runs upwards, the slope of the line representing the plane is now 1/v. One can rescale the coordinates by expressing velocity as a fraction of some convenient velocity (say the speed of light... although at this stage nothing is special about that speed) so this normalized velocity is now dimensionless $\beta$. Thus the slope is now $1/\beta$.

Later, one distinction between Galilean and Special relativity is how one calibrates the tickmarks along that axis.